# Looking for Delphi 4 professional/Quickreport

Tags: delphi, delphi-4

I'm looking for Delphi 4 professional and quickreport to support a legacy application. Where I can find this?

Comment: SO is not a classified advertising site

Comment: Fair enough. I have a legacy application that I urgently need help supporting. I've updated my question below and If your a delphi expert would really appreciate input. Thanks

Comment: I have a original Delphi 4 CD here from 1998 with valid license... Write me an e-mail, if interested...

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 4 was mostly abandoned when Delphi 5 came out. You can still find Delphi 5 on Ebay. If you're not using any components, the code is compatible between versions.

Comment: Hi, 

I've taken over a legacy application and I have the exe created. If I can configure the BDE then in theory it should be possible to run this. Someone indicated that Delphi needs to be installed in order for the app to run. I'm unsure of that - it doesn't quite make sense to me as there is an exe file.

Any input from Delphi experts would be appreciated.

Roddy

Comment: Besides the BDE, it depends on how the Delphi project was built.  By default, most of the libraries are built and linked into the application, and therefore, you shouldn't require anything further. Because some applications still require the BDE it's still available on the Internet from third parties. Google "BDE 5.2 DOWNLOAD".

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly it should be included in at least some older Delphi versions. Get a second-hand Delphi 4, 5, 6, or 7 and do a Component/Install package..., navigate to Delphi's bin folder and install dclqrt*.bpl and it should work.